# Save bash $$ value in variable

Tags: bash, tmux

I set up my terminal so that when I open one it attaches to a tmux group session and creates a new window; the main session is shared among all terminals, but every one gets a clean window to work on.

I would like to name this window with the process id of the bash running in it. 
Basically, I run the script

```
MYPIDVAR=$$ 
export PS1="[\u@${MYPIDVAR} \W]\$ " 

[[ ! $TERM =~ screen ]] && exec tmux new-session -s test \; new-window -n ${MYPIDVAR}
```

and expect both my command prompt and tmux window title to be the same. However I end up with two different numbers, like 5575 (on the bash prompt) and 5566 (as window title).

Below is my original question, which was a little too confused.

---

To do so I run the command

```
exec tmux -2 new-session -t main \; new-window -n $ID \; set-option destroy-unattached
```

where `ID` is set to `$$` at the beginning of the script

```
ID=$$
```

however the title of the window in tmux ends up being different from the bash pid. Here the window title is 2187

```
[maldus@2166 ~]$ echo $$
2166
[maldus@2166 ~]$ ps aux | grep 2156
maldus    2156  0.0  0.0  26564  4032 pts/0    Ss+  14:20   0:00 tmux -2 new-session -t main ; new-window -n 2156 ; set-option destroy-unattached
maldus    2164  0.0  0.0  35280  4000 ?        Ss   14:20   0:00 tmux -2 new-session -t main ; new-window -n 2156 ; set-option destroy-unattached
maldus    2187  0.0  0.0  10884  2288 pts/2    S+   14:20   0:00 grep 2156
```

So it appears that `$ID` is resolved as `$$` and interpreted as the pid of the child process starting tmux, rather than having the value 2166 stored from before.
What I need at this point is to save the string value output from $$ instead of immediately substituting it in the whole script. I've tried the following:

```
ID=`echo $$`
ID="$$"
ID='$$'
ID="$(echo $$)"
```

with no luck.

I'm sure there is a simple solution to this, I just can't seem to put together a google search with the right keywords.

Comment: `ID=$$` will assign the string value, there's no point doubting that. Are you assuming that the newly started bash shell will have the same pid as your original bash shell? This is not true and not something you can make happen when tmux comes between then.

Comment: As @thatotherguy said, `ID=$$` will set ID the string value of the pid, so the problem must lie somewhere in your startup scripts or your tmux configuration. Perhaps `ID` is unexpectedly being changed or set somewhere. It's not obvious precisely how you're starting your terminal windows and initial tmux session from what you've shared. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I edited the question using a minimal example

Answer (score 2):

Use `PPID` instead of `$$`, or set `ID` to it:

```
export ID=$PPID
```

Works in bash and zsh

Comment: What behaves the same way as what?

Comment: The bash and the tmux window have two different pids, like the example in the question